# How can I list all rows in table and count from multiple table that related with each rows?

Tags: mysql

I have made Q & A website that a questions can have tags in it and the user can subscribe to tags they want. So, I have create tag page for list all tags and count all questions and users who subscribed to these tags.I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944099/mysql-count-on-multiple-tables) but it more complex for me.
The code below is SQL I'm trying and it seems very slow for query times. I want SQL below is to write by using `JOIN/LEFT JOIN/RIGHT JOIN` I think it will be faster. But I have no idea.

**SQL**

```
select tag.*,
    (select count(*) from taggedquestion where taggedquestion.tagid = tag.id) questionCount, 
    (select count(*) from tagsubscription where tagsubscription.tagid = tag.id) userCount 
from tag order by tag.id asc
```

**Tags page**

```
 Tag name             question count         user count
----------------------------------------------------------------
 computer               12                      5
 science                10                      3
 travel                 6                       2
 programing             18                      3
 ...                    ...                     ...
 ...                    ...                     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select tag.*,
       (select count(*) from taggedquestion where taggedquestion.tagid = tag.id and ids = '0'
       ) as questionCount, 
       (select count(*) from tagsubscription where tagsubscription.tagid = tag.id and ids = '0'
       ) as userCount 
from tag
order by tag.id asc;
```

This is a reasonable query.  Probably what you need for performance are the following indexes (if you don't already have them):

```
taggedquestion(tagid, ids)
tagsubscription(tagid, ids)
tag(id)
```

You probably already have the last one, because `id` is presumably a primary key on the `tag` table.

Answer (score 0):

On your second posted query, you are missing `SELECT` and so getting the posted error. Your second query should look like below

```
SELECT tag.*, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taggedquestion
 LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = taggedquestion.tagid 
 and taggedquestion.ids = '0') AS postCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagsubscription
 LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = tagsubscription.tagid 
 and tagsubscription.ids = '0') AS userCount 
 FROM tag
```

Try like this then using `SUM` with `CASE` condition. Since you haven't shown your tables structure or sample data; can't say for sure but you might want to `group by` the `taggedquestion.ids` like

```
SELECT tag.*, 
( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN taggedquestion.ids = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 FROM taggedquestion
 INNER JOIN tag 
 ON tag.id = taggedquestion.tagid 
 GROUP BY taggedquestion.ids) AS postCount, 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tagsubscription.ids = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 FROM tagsubscription
 INNER JOIN tag 
 ON tag.id = tagsubscription.tagid 
 GROUP BY tagsubscription.ids) AS userCount 
 FROM tag
```

Comment: yeah, but it give a wrong results, it seems ignore the condition. i got `postCount` = total rows in `taggedquestion` and `userCount` = total rows in `tagsubscription` with all rows of tag table

Comment: still not working, look at my question again i have edited. and i just want to covert my query to using some of `JOIN`. Thanks.

Comment: Try the edited query as well consider providing table structure along with sample data (or a sql fiddle) for further help.